# Сохранение авторизации во Flutter

Tags: авторизация, flutter

Вопрос в следующем:

Имеются endpoitы на сервере, доступ к которым происходит через Basic auth.
Например, для доступа к списку постов делается get запрос к /api/posts и передается заголовок `Authorization : base64Encode<userlogin,userpass>`.

В случае успеха 200 статускод как обычно, в случае неудачи код 40*.

**Пример кода**

```
// Кодируем данные
String base64Auth = stringToBase64.encode("${login}:${password}");

http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic $base64Auth"
      },
    ).then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
       
      // В случае успеха нужно как-то запомнить пользователя, 
      // чтобы после перезапуска приложения авторизация сохранилась
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        
        // Эта переменная сбросится в начальное состояние (false) после перезапуска
        isLoggedIn = true;

        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, Constants.ROUTE_HOME, (route) => false);
      } else {
        return 'Ошибка авторизации. Проверьте логин и пароль';
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      //Отправка ошибки на сервер

      return 'Неизвестная ошибка.';
    });
```

В общем вопрос, как реализовать нечто наподобие cookies на flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно получить cookie (или с помощью библиотеки [CookieJar](https://pub.dev/packages/cookie_jar)):

```
String base64Auth = stringToBase64.encode("${login}:${password}");

Map<String, String> headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Basic $base64Auth"
};

http.get(url, headers: headers).then((http.Response response) {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    cookie(response);
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context, Constants.ROUTE_HOME, (route) => false);
  } else {
    return 'Ошибка авторизации. Проверьте логин и пароль';
  }
}).catchError((err) {
  return 'Неизвестная ошибка.';
});

void cookie(http.Response response) {
  String rawCookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
  if (rawCookie != null) {
    int index = rawCookie.indexOf(';');
    headers['cookie'] = (index == -1) ? rawCookie : rawCookie.substring(0, index);
  }
}
```

Но для того чтобы использовать их после перезапуска приложения, необходимо сохронять эти данные. Для этого можно использовать: [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) и т.д.